# Running Liferay docker behind Apache httpd as a reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, liferay

I try to run Liferay docker behind Apache httpd but cannot get it work properly.

- The Home link url is `https://myserver.com:20180/web/guest/home`. When I click on it I get a 404 with a message `The requested URL /web/guest/home was not found on this server.`
- When I load the url `https://myserver.com:20180/dxp` this is what I get lots of errors:

[image]

**/opt/liferay/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties**

```
web.server.protocol=https
web.server.host=myserver.com
web.server.http.port=80
web.server.https.port=20180

portal.ctx=/dxp

redirect.url.security.mode=domain
redirect.url.domains.allowed=myserver.com
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# LIFERAY DXP
liferay-dxp-latest:
    image: "liferay/portal:7.3.1-ga2"
    container_name: liferay-dxp-latest
    mem_reservation: 512m
    mem_limit: 4g
    cpu_quota: 100000
    environment:
        TZ: Etc/GMT
        JMS_BROKER_CHECK: 1
    volumes:
        - ./liferay-dxp/autodeploy:/opt/liferay/deploy
    ports:
        - "20202:8080"
    networks:
        mynetwork: 
            aliases:
                - liferay-dxp

# APACHE HTTPD
apache-httpd-latest:
    image: "dockerrepo:5000/apache-httpd:2.4"
    container_name: latest-apache-httpd
    mem_reservation: 512m
    mem_limit: 512m
    cpu_quota: 100000
    volumes:
        - ./common/shared:/shared
        - ./common/shared/proxy/static:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/static
        - ./common/shared/portal:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/portal

    ports:
        - "20180:8443"
    networks:
        - mynetwork
```

**httpd.conf**

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2/"

#
# Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
# for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
#
# Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
# mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
# other reason.
#
# Mutex default:logs

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
# Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
#LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
#LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
#LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
#LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
#LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
#LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
#LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
#LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule evasive20_module modules/mod_evasive24.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "/proc/self/fd/2"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel debug

    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%t %V %{X-Forwarded-For}i %h \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined2
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
    # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log combined2

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined


<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts.
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "/usr/local/apache2//cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2//cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddType text/html .shtml
    #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
# returning the entire resource, or one of the special
# values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
# Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
#MaxRanges unlimited

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it,
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
#
# uncomment out the below to deal with user agents that deliberately
# violate open standards by misusing DNT (DNT *must* be a specific
# end-user choice)
#
#<IfModule setenvif_module>
#BrowserMatch "MSIE 10.0;" bad_DNT
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule headers_module>
#RequestHeader unset DNT env=bad_DNT
#</IfModule>
#Listen  443
Listen  8443
Listen  8080

#switch off destination SSL check
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off

#used for apache 2.4.6 and invalid proxy certificates
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

# Rate limiting
# Learn more at http://library.linode.com/web-servers/apache/mod-evasive
<IfModule evasive20_module>
    # The hash table size defines the number of top-level nodes for each child's
    # hash table. Increasing this number will provide faster performance by
    # decreasing the number of iterations required to get to the record, but
    # consume more memory for table space. You should increase this if you have
    # a busy web server. The value you specify will automatically be tiered up
    # to the next prime number in the primes list (see mod_evasive.c for a list
    # of primes used).
    DOSHashTableSize 3097

    # If set, this email address will receive a notification whenever an IP
    # address becomes blacklisted. A locking mechanism prevents continous
    # emails from being sent.
    # DOSEmailNotify admin@example.org

    # NOTE: The following settings apply on a per-IP address basis.

    # Allow up to 5 requests for the same URI per second:
    DOSPageInterval 1
    DOSPageCount 50

    # Allow up to 1000 requests across the site per second:
    DOSSiteInterval 1
    DOSSiteCount 1000

    # Once the client is blacklisted, prevent them from accessing the site
    # for 10 seconds:
    DOSBlockingPeriod 5
</IfModule>

#wildcard certificate
#<VirtualHost *:443>
#
#   SSLEngine on
#   Protocol https
#   ServerName localhost:443
#
#   SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
#   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"
#
#</VirtualHost>
#
#
#<VirtualHost  *:443>
#
#   #RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-SSL true
#
#   <Location />
#       Order allow,deny
#       Allow from all
#       <LimitExcept POST GET>
#           Deny from all
#       </LimitExcept>
#   </Location>
#
#   #Config SSL
#
#
#   SSLEngine on
#   SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
#   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"
#
#   <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
#       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
#   </FilesMatch>
#   <Directory "/usr/local/apache2//cgi-bin">
#       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
#   </Directory>
#
#   BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
#            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
#            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
#
#
#   CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2//logs/ssl_request_log" \
#             "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost   *:8443>

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST GET DELETE>
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Location>

    #RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-SSL true

    #Config SSL
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2//cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


    CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2//logs/MAINTENANCE_ssl_request_log" \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    #Redirection LIFERAY-DXP
    ProxyPass        /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost   *:8080>

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <LimitExcept POST GET>
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Location>

    #RequestHeader set WL-Proxy-SSL true

    #Config SSL
    #SSLEngine on

    #SSLCertificateFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.crt"
    #SSLCertificateKeyFile "/usr/local/apache2/conf/server.key"

    #<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    #   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    #</FilesMatch>
    #<Directory "/usr/local/apache2//cgi-bin">
    #   SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    #</Directory>

    #BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    #        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    #        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


    #CustomLog "/usr/local/apache2//logs/MAINTENANCE_ssl_request_log" \
    #         "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

    #CustomLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/access.log combined
    #ErrorLog /usr/local/apache2/logs/error.log

    #Redirection LIFERAY-DXP
    ProxyPass        /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080
    ProxyPassReverse /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

Could you please help me on this please?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

You redirect `https://myserver.com:8443/dxp` and `https://myserver.com:8080/dxp` internally to `http://liferay-dxp:8080`:

```
 ProxyPass        /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080
 ProxyPassReverse /dxp http://liferay-dxp:8080
```

But your Liferay opens port 20202, right?

```
ports:
    - "20202:8080"
```

And within Docker, Liferay does not listen to 8080 (nor 20202), although I am not familiar with this:

```
web.server.https.port=20180
```